# Oracle 10.x to MySQL 5.x Conversion

Tags: php, mysql, oracle10g, database-migration

I have existing project database with Oracle 10g version and I want to convert / create replica with Arabic records in MySQL.

Is there any tool or ready made PHP script available for same?

Please let me know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download this file , this may help you,

```
http://www.convert-in.com/demos/ora2sqld.exe
```

Here is the tutorial,

```
http://www.convert-in.com/oracle-to-mysql-tutorial.htm
```

Comment: Hi, Kiran, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I noticed that you've posted several answers, like this one, which only link to an external website. While they may technically answer the question, it would be [much better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) if you could summarize the main point(s) of the pages you link to in your own words, if only so that your answers won't become useless if the links stop working some day in the future. Thanks, and have a nice day!

Comment: thanks , i will consider it. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It was not much helpful, but I exported data in `SQL` format via SQL Developer and then some `find/replace` stuffs and finally imported via `MySQL Command Prompt`